# Having some issues with JQuery, it appears that I can't get it to work

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery

I am working on a web based project mostly using python and using a PyCharm compiler.

For the project I needed to download JQuery but it appears not to be working. I'm not entirely sure what the issue is. I downloaded the files right from the website and have structured my code to be the same as the teacher that I am using. When I went to download the code I had to use the save as option and put it in a java script file but I followed the method that I found on tutorial sites so I don't know why that would be an issue.

The code for the JQuery section doesn't provide drop-down menus for commands and the color of the font doesn't change for most of the script like it does in other sections.

Here are pictures of sections of code for the JQuery and the file itself. The JQuery file I thought looked strange but I re-downloaded it again and it came out the same.

[This is part of the main layout HTML file where I call the Java-script file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sXDE.png)

[This is the Java-script file where I noticed that the commands didn't seem to be working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2pLe.png)

[This image is what the Jquery min file came out to look like, for some reason its just a single line of code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryueZ.png)

If anyone know can spot why the JQuery commands don't seem to be working and can tell me how to correct the issue it would be appreciated.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Is scripty really named just scipty or is it scripty.js and is it in the correct directory in comparison to your html file?

Comment: The min file _should_ only be a single line.  It's a minimized file, so spaces/line breaks/etc are stripped to make the file no larger than necessary.

Comment: You could try using JSFiddle (or similar) to test the JQuery code itself.  You should also check your web browser's console to see what possible error(s) you're running into.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, there isn't enough of your code for a proper diagnosis - but at least we can give you a few tips (a) to fix parts of your project and (b) to get better/faster results from future StackOverflow questions. SO please consider this a long comment.

First, I notice that you are loading jQuery twice - first from a CDN:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and also from a file on your webserver:

Remove the second ("Static") one - the CDN is implemented correctly and should work fine.

The way to solve a problem like this is to "Divide And Conquer". First, remove all javascript/jQuery code except:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("Here I yam");
});
```

If you get that alert box after refreshing the page, then your jQuery and javascript are working correctly.

Next, add in the rest of the code a bit at a time and test after each bit you add. Make sure that you learn to use DevTools (F12) ! Watch videos if you don't. DevTools will save you tons of time in the end.

I used PyCharm once-upon-a-time, and switched away from it to VSCode. I didn't want to like VSCode... I try not to like anything from Microsoft... but it's absolutely amazing (and totally FREE). Make sure you install the Python extension and watch a couple of short videos on using VSCode to develop python apps. You will never go back.

Finally, the 2nd and 3rd comments under your question (from Jason and Nathan) are correct and important for you.